# Test header color using java and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, css, selenium, colors

I have to test header of the webpage to make sure it has correct color(#FFFFFF). Color value stored in css. I was trying to do this, but it doesn't work.

```
String headerColor = 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*  [@id='title']/h1")).getCssValue("color");
Assert.assertTrue("#000000", sColor.equals("#FFFFFF"));}
```

Help me to do this correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How it's not working? What's the `headerColor` you got? Where's `sColor` defined in your code?

Not sure if you just pasted it wrong or what, here's what I'd try:

```
String headerColor = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='title']/h1")).getCssValue("color");
// System.out.println("Actual value: " + headerColor);
Assert.assertEquals("some message", "#FFFFFF", headerColor);
```

Comment: Thank you. headerColor and sColor are the same in my code. For stackoverflow i changed scolor to headerColor(to make it more understandable), but forgot to change it in second place. I just tried yours, test case work, but fails.The massage is: Expected :#FFFFFF
Actual   :rgba(255, 255, 255, 1). But they are both color white!?

Comment: @ReuvenVolnoboy: Yes, they are just different ways of representing web colors. `#FFFFFF` is [hex triplet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors), `rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)` is [RGBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space). Probably your style sheet uses `rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)`, so Selenium evaluates `rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)`. All you need to do is changing the expected value to the same format with what Selenium gets. In this case: `Assert.assertEquals("some message", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)", headerColor);`

Answer (score 0):

let’s check out how to verify color in Selenium WebDriver.

For purpose of our example, we will verify color of Products link present in About Google page. Below image shows this link.
https://www.google.co.in/intl/en/about/

I have describe all the steps in the below link.

http://www.testingdiaries.com/verify-color-in-selenium-webdriver/

I am sure you will find the solution and you can reply me if you have any query about that.